# I accidentally overwrote my build folder trying to create a dev server in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have an existing project in Firebase that is already in production (a React web app) but I'm in the process of trying to create a dev server. I created another project then proceeded with the steps in the CLI as I figured they were appropriate:

```
firebase use bizzy-book-dev
firebase init      
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

The dev site wasn't displaying so I checked the firebase dev project and it showed I only had 8 files in the release history (I should have 48...):

[image]

I couldn't get it to work so I decided to try at a later date. When I switched back to my production project, made changes and deployed, I noticed that whatever I did earlier affected my main project. I've rolled back so my site is live but I'm stuck not being able to make updates.

[image]

I have two questions:

1. How do I fix this build issue?
2. How do I get a dev server up when I have an existing firebase project?

Comment: It's not really possible for us to help fix a problem that we don't know how you got into. We need specific steps to reproduce the problem, including the content that you're working with.  Just those three commands isn't enough for a repro. :(

Comment: If you think the Firebase CLI is not working the way it should, then you'll definitely need to set up a series of reproducible steps that lead to the wrong result, and post that as a bug report on GitHub. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: @DougStevenson I thought I was pretty clear.. I had an existing project that was already deployed to firebase.. In my attempt to create a dev server, I created a new project, and ran those commands... thats it...

Comment: It's that existing project state that we don't know about.  If your repro steps start with no project at all and walks through everything to get to where you are now, that would be immensely helpful.

Comment: @DougStevenson I apologize, as I'm still learning.. but the main project has been deployed for quite some time now, over a year.. I just made the decision to add a dev server for features that would require additional development and testing instead of continuously deploying to the main project.. long story short, I'm not quite sure what you need.. I'll do my research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your specific project layout, provide a sample public project so it gets easier to advise you.

Besides that, where you using just hosting or any other firebase service?

For instance, you might have changed something on your firebase.json regarding [the public folder configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#hosting_priority_order). Docs says that it might happen if you call firebase init twice.

Besides that, take a look at the [emulators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite), they might help a lot when you want to test something but don't want to publish your changes every single time you tweak something. [I am studying firebase too](https://github.com/sombriks/sample-firebase) and so far they help to test several concepts and enhance productivity for solutions using firebase as platform. Give them a try!